# Is twos complement a representation or an algorithm or both?

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, computer-science, twos-complement

There are tons of previous threads about how to apply 2's complement and how to interpret the number which I fully understand; however, what I'm confused about is the technical definition: that is,  is 2's complement the binary representation i.e. 1011 = -5  or is it the method i.e. `complement_2(1011) = 0101` or is it both of these together?

Comment: It's a representation. There are algorithms for *manipulating* a number in two's-complement form, including converting to and from other forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opinions about "proper usage" of the term aside, in practice the term "two's complement" is used for both:

- An operation (as in "taking the two's complement of an integer")
- A system of representing integers based on that operation

Evidence #1, quoted from the [Wikipedia about two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) with emphasis added:

> Two's complement is **a mathematical operation** [...] It is used in computer science as **the most common method of representing** signed (positive, negative, and zero) integers on computers

As a bonus, the "it" in the second sentence seems to refer to both the operation and the representation at the same time.

Evidence #2, [Techopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/22684/twos-complement)

> The “two’s complement” in IT is an operation on binary numbers, and a way to record these numbers through mathematical manipulation, to define both positive and negative integers in binary. It has been described by experts as a “binary signed number representation” that has to do with signed and unsigned values for eight-bit binary or other binary numbers.

Answer (score 1):

While there are various definitions of **representation**, the relevant one here refers to signs or symbols that convey information, point to objects, ideas, concepts...

The symbols `0`, `1` arranged in a positional notation could constitute 2's complement as a representation, but this definition could equally apply to binary numbers that are not intended to be in 2's complement.

Numbers could equally be represented as high / low voltage states within an electronic circuit. This could also be a 2's complement representation.

Thus there can be many different ways of representing the same concept.

What the various representations have in common are the rules for manipulating the values or symbols (symbols are things that can be manipulated *as if* they were the thing they represent)

---

It's hard to definitively answer the question but I would try:

> An *agreement or intention to interpret a representation* (in some sort of binary format) as being 2's complement with its associated rules for manipulation.

Comment: This is just what I could think of off the top of my head, it's not an authoritative answer.

Comment: Seems pretty reasonable and intuitive to me. Will give it a while to see if anyone else has a different perspective but if not I will mark as the answer. Thank you for replying!